# How to define belongs to association with different aliases

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

Am trying to find a way to handle the association between two models (User and Group). The problem here is Group can have multiple users( they can be members of a group / they can be attendees of some event/programme which belongs to the same group)

Relationship between the group and users are : 
User belongs to multiple groups.
groups can have multiple users.

The solution that I tried

```
User.belongsToMany(Group, {through: UserGroup, as : 'Members'});
User.belongsToMany(Group, {through: UserGroup, as : 'Attendees'});
Group.belongsToMany(User, {through: UserGroup, as : 'Users'});
```

User Model

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports  = (sequelize) => {
    return sequelize.define('ssuser', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoincrement: true,
        allowNull : false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull : false
    },
    firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
    lastName: Sequelize.STRING
});
}
```

Group Model :

```
module.exports  = (sequelize) => {
    return sequelize.define('ssgroup', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoincrement: true,
        allowNull : false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    ownerId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull : false,
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull : false
    },
    description: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull : false
    },
    groupType: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull : false
    }
});
}
```

Association USERGROUP

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports  = (sequelize) => {
    return sequelize.define('userGroup', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoincrement: true,
        allowNull : false,
        primaryKey: true
    }
});
}
```

Am not sure how this will help me to find the members of the group alone or attendees of the group alone.

I expect the association table should have columns "Attendee" "Member".
So that it would be easier to retrieve the data of users who are members of a particular group.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to have some flag in the `userGroup` table indicating the user membership type, e.g. "member", "attendee", or "user". It can be integer or enum. Then, you will be able to filter users in the group based on type. Maybe it will solve your problem and you won't even need to have three `belongsToMany` relations? You would just have one for the regular users, but filtering will be done programmatically when retrieving data.

Comment: Thanks, @AnnaPohorielova, I have followed the same trick to fix my problem. It worked well.

Comment: But when I try to add a user to a group through association method `(Group.addUser(user))` with the flag set as a member and again if I add the same user as an attendee, the existing entry just gets updated as an attendee instead of adding a new one. But I need it as a new entry.

Comment: You can create a `userGroup` record directly through the association model: `UserGroup.create({group_id: 1, user_id: 1, membership_type: 'member'})`. This way the query will be directly run on the `userGroup` table as `INSERT` and will insert a new record each time.